# Start-Job\Receive-Job is hanging\freezing while getting results - PrimalForm CE GUI

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-4.0

I can start the job but how can I continue using my program while its getting the information, if I do a 'while' loop it just freezes the program until the results have completed.

Here is the script generated by PrimalForms CE edition, and my code is in `button1_OnClick`.

End result I want to have the script running to check for locked out AD users (but that can really be anything) then while that is running I want to review the previous results and unlock a user if needed...

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
  ########################################################################
  # Code Generated By: SAPIEN Technologies PrimalForms (Community Edition)      v1.0.10.0
  # Generated On: 7/09/2015 2:24 PM
  # Generated By: stojanp2
  ########################################################################

  #region Import the Assemblies
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
  #endregion

  #region Generated Form Objects
  $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $listView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
  $button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Users = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader
  $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
  #endregion Generated Form Objects

  #----------------------------------------------
  #Generated Event Script Blocks
  #----------------------------------------------
  #Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
  $button3_OnClick =
  {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
  }

  $button1_OnClick =
  {
    Start-Job -Name FindUsers -ScriptBlock { Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | Select-Object * }#end Start-Job

    Do {
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
       write-host "waiting" # so i can see its doing something in the console
    } Until (@(Get-Job -Name FindUsers).State -eq "Completed")

    Write-Host "done"

    $us = Receive-Job -Name FindUsers
    ForEach ($u IN $us){
      $listView1.Items.Add($u.sAMAccountName)
    }

    Get-Job -Name FindUsers | Remove-Job -Force
  }

  $button2_OnClick =
  {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
  }

  $handler_listView1_SelectedIndexChanged =
  {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
  }

  $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection =
  { #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
  }

  #----------------------------------------------
  #region Generated Form Code
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 469
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 271
  $form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
  $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $form1.Name = "form1"
  $form1.Text = "Primal Form"

  $button3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

  $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
  $System_Drawing_Point.X = 142
  $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 418
  $button3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
  $button3.Name = "button3"
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 117
  $button3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
  $button3.TabIndex = 3
  $button3.Text = "button3"
  $button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $button3.add_Click($button3_OnClick)

  $form1.Controls.Add($button3)

  $button2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

  $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
  $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
  $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 418
  $button2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
  $button2.Name 

  = "button2"
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 117
  $button2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
  $button2.TabIndex = 2
  $button2.Text = "button2"
  $button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $button2.add_Click($button2_OnClick)

  $form1.Controls.Add($button2)

  $listView1.Columns.Add($Users)|Out-Null
  $listView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
  $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
  $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 73
  $listView1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
  $listView1.Name = "listView1"
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 339
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 247
  $listView1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
  $listView1.TabIndex = 1
  $listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = $False
  $listView1.View = 1
  $listView1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($handler_listView1_SelectedIndexChanged)

  $form1.Controls.Add($listView1)

  $button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

  $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
  $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
  $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 12
  $button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
  $button1.Name = "button1"
  $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
  $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 55
  $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 247
  $button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
  $button1.TabIndex = 0
  $button1.Text = "button1"
  $button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $button1.add_Click($button1_OnClick)

  $form1.Controls.Add($button1)

  $Users.Name = "Users"
  $Users.Text = "User Names"
  $Users.Width = 116

  #endregion Generated Form Code

  #Save the initial state of the form
  $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
  #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
  $form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
  #Show the Form
  $form1.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about PrimalForm but in PowerShell Studio there is a seperate button called `Button - Start Job` in the section `Toolbox > Control Sets`:

[image]

When using this type of button an extra function is provided called `Add-JobTracker` that keeps track of the job progress and makes sure that the job is ran in the background in its own PowerShell session. So it doesn't freeze the interface and even updates a progress bar if you will.

More info on the SAPIEN page [PowerShell Studio: Creating responsive forms](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/05/16/powershell-studio-creating-responsive-forms/).

The fact that your are doing a loop to check every time the status of the job is why the interface freezes. It will stop every time at that point and only frees up again when the job is completely done.

Maybe if you update PrimalForms to the latest version you'll have this function to.